# Center rendered mxGraph svg

Tags: svg, alignment, rendering, center, mxgraph

I'm using [mxGraph](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph) to render a Graph, but I didn't find yet a way to render it centered. I've tried display:block to it and margin:auto on the svg style, but it had no effect.
Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should help you:

[mxGraph.prototype.center](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.center) – centers the graph in the container